# What's the intuitive explanation of (∀xFx → Gn) ≡∃x(Fx →Gn)?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Suppose there are `m, n, o` in the domain of x

Then

```
(1) (∀xFx → Gn) ≡ ((Fm∧Fn∧Fo)->Gn)

(2) ∃x(Fx →Gn) ≡ (Fm→Gn)∨(Fn→Gn)∨(Fo→Gn)
```

How can (1) and (2) be equivalent? Since (1) says that all Fm, Fn, Fo have to be true so that Gn. (2) say that it's possible that Fm is true will guarantee Gn.

Any explanation in English? I know how to prove it in predicate language, it's just that intuitively it feels strange.

Comment: Looks like negation of universal quantifier is existence quantifier.

Comment: See [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication)

Comment: 2) is equiv to $(\lnot Fm \lor Gn) ∨ (\lnot Fn \lor Gn) ∨ (\lnot Fo \lor Gn)$ and 1) is equiv to $\lnot(Fm ∧ Fn ∧ Fo) \lor Gn$

Comment: Consider the possible cases: if $Gn$ is True, both formulas are True. What happens with $Gn$ False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting your $(1)$ and $(2):$

> $$∀xFx → Gn\tag{1a}$$ $$(Fm∧Fn∧Fo)→Gn\tag{1b}$$
> $$∃x(Fx →Gn)\tag{2a}$$ $$(Fm→Gn)∨(Fn→Gn)∨(Fo→Gn)\tag{2b}$$

Let's consider the truth of $Gn.$

Now, $(2\text b)$ claims that one of its conditionals must be true. But since we don't know which, if we wish to *guarantee* $Gn$'s truth, we do require all three of $Fm,Fn,$ and $Fo$ to be true.

But this is precisely what $(1\text b)$ is claiming: if we wish to *guarantee* $Gn$'s truth, we need all three of $Fm,Fn,$ and $Fo$ to be true.

Does this give a better sense of how/why $(1)\equiv(2)?$